# Google Site: Is there a way to automatically add to a section in Google Site whenever I receive an email containing certain text

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-docs-api, google-sites

Problem: I created a google site.  I would like this site to have a running section and what is populated in this section are certain emails that I would like to upload there, either text or PDF.  Preferably text though.  Is this possible in anyway via google apps script or something?  Trying to stay OOTB as possible

If there's another way that this can be done, please let me know!  Thanks!

I'm trying to google to see if it is but I don't see any way possible of doing this.

EDIT: The only way I see it is to embed a google doc on the site and then take in all emails and write a GAS script to save the email into the google doc.  Thoughts?  Is this even possible?

Comment: If you run a function on a time based trigger you could search through the inbox threads and find it and put it in a queue and the the next time your site gets opened a function could look through the queue and display the results.  May be there are other solutions. Maybe you have some more ideas.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper!  I was thinking of setting up a label and so all emails I would need to parse would fall under this label (I already have something like this for another project using GmailApp class).  I would then parse the email and take the body.

I guess my question is this: is there an API to write to google doc?

EDIT: found it https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/overview

has anyone ever done this before?

Comment: You could just make it a web app.  Deploy it and paste the url into the embed box